# Responsive hero image as CSS background image?

Tags: css

For my responsive site I want to have a hero image as a background image not an image in the html.

I can make the div be 100% width easily, but im not sure how to make it have the correct height. I have to set a height in px but the height required depends on the div's width, which varies as the site is responsive.

```
<div class="cont">
  <p>Below is an image in the html that scales correctly</p> 
  <img src="http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg" />
  <p>The example below is a background image in CSS</p>
  <div class="hero-img"></div>
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

.cont {
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.hero-img {
  background: url("http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FBxkz

[image]

UPDATE - Background-size cover or contain do not fix my problem. The div with the image still has a fixed height.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FCafi

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `background-size: 100% 100%;` to `background-size: cover;`

[**More on `background-size:cover` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

> **cover**
>
> This keyword specifies that the background image should be scaled to be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions
>   are greater than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the
>   background positioning area.

nb. Per the comment from [**Terry**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395910/terry) below, you may also want to add `background-position: center center;` to ensure the image stays centred.

Comment: Also useful: `background-position: center center;` to ensure that the image, after scaling with `cover` to fit the container, is centered in the element :)

Comment: Ive updated my question to explain why background-size does not fully solve my problem.

Comment: @jdln - so you want the `div` to grow/shrink keeping the images aspect ratio? Im afraid you need to use an `img` for this, it isnt possible using `div` without additionally adding JS overhead, `div` and `img` are two fundamentally different elements.

Answer (score 2):

`background-size: cover;` will crop the image to ensure the entire div is covered by it. If you want to prevent cropping, you can use `background-size: contain;`.

The behaviour is similar, but using `contain` forces the background image to be scaled to ensure that its dimensions are *smaller* than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background positioning area.

Comment: Ive updated my question to explain why background-size cover or contain do not fully solve my problem.

Comment: that solution worked for me perfectly, using contain was a nice idea as compared to cover, cover was failing at a point and was cropping image but using contain the image is now responsive just like the `img-responsive` tag of bootstrap3

Answer (score 0):

Background size:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Ive updated my question to explain why background-size cover does not fully solve my problem.